# PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in

Tags: pdo, prepared-statement, bind

I'm having a problem with a prepared Update query:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("
        UPDATE articles SET 
        title = :title, 
        body = :body, 
        intro = :intro, 
        datePub = :datePub, 
        authorID = :authorID', 
        author = :author', 
        category = :category, 
        tags = :tags, 
        language = :language, 
        visible = :visible, 
        translatedArt = :translatedArt, 
        relatedArts = :relatedArts, 
        priority = :priority, 
        changefreq = :changefreq
        WHERE 
        id= :id"
        );


        $stmt->bindParam(':title', $title, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':body', $bodyArt, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':intro', $intro, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':datePub', $datePub, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':authorID', $author, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':author', $authorName, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':category', $cat, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':tags', $tags, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':language', $language, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':visible', $visibility, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':translatedArt', $transArt, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':relatedArts', $relArtCombi, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':priority', $priority, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':changefreq', $changeFreq, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':id', $operation, PDO::PARAM_INT);

        $stmt->execute();
```

I'm binding 15 variables and I have 15 parameters in the query, do you have any idea on why I'm getting the error?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the apostrophe `'` on

```
authorID = :authorID', 
author = :author',
```

so that it can be :

```
 authorID = :authorID, 
 author = :author,
```

Comment: Thanks! what a st**id I am! :-)

Comment: pleasure don't forget to mark the answer @paolo9785